# Django - Upload / Template

Tags: django

I'm trying to display an image on my template but it's a little difficult.

I don't know how to get my images on my static folder. In this foder, there's an "Image" folder where's all my images.

Here's the code :

```
{% for document in documents %}
<div id="fiche-photo" class="col-md-6">
{% if document.actif %}
  <img src="{%static "images/temp/"%}" class="img-responsive" />
{% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I know the model and form are good, and I tested a normal src but with the template it's a little difficult.

Here is the model :

```
class Documents(models.Model):
docTypeId = models.ForeignKey('DocType', null=True)
entrepriseId = models.ForeignKey('Entreprise', null=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
fileName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
actif = models.BooleanField()
url = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

def docFileName(self):
    return "documents/" + str(self.entrepriseId.id) + "/" + str(self.id) + ".jpg"
docFileName = property(docFileName)
```

If you have some ideas, i'm open with it :)

Have a nice day :)

Comment: did you make sure your static files variable points to the right drectory in settings. ?   
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#settings-staticfiles

Comment: What is `static`? Shouldn't it be `{{ photo.url }}`?

Comment: @Selcuk static is a folder where there's my JS folder, image folder, font folder, etc. I can try photo.url.

Comment: @Selcuk is probably right.. it possibly should be photo.url. But, is there a url property on photo model

Comment: @selcuk I edited my post and I forgot I have a temp folder in my images folder. My images are in this folder. Edit : It's in my model "Documents" so there's not "photo" sorry ^^'

Comment: I think you are confusing some of the concepts in Django development. I suggest that you follow a tutorial first. You should also post the exact code you are having problems with, not a fictitious code snippet.

Comment: Can you post your model so that we can show you how to add the image in corretly?

Comment: Here is the model, i work on the template.

Comment: I found the solution. Excuse me everyone but i didn't show all my code, you didn't have elements to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
<img src="{%static "images/temp/"%}" class="img-responsive" />
```

is going to throw an error because of the quotes around and within the `static` tag.

Try:

```
<img src="{%static 'images/temp/'%}" class="img-responsive" />
```